# How to filter data class properties by kotlin annotation?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, annotations, data-class

Implimentation of Annotation

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Returnable
```

Dummy Data class

```
data class DataClass(
    val property: String
    @Returnable
    val annotatedProperty: String
)
```

Java Reflections filtering doesn't work

```
this::class.memberProperties
        .filter{ it.annotations.map { ann -> ann.annotationClass }.contains(Returnable::class)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin annotation isn't the same as Java annotations. So work with Kotlin reflection requires a bit different way compare to classic java. Here you can find a way of filtering properties of Kotlin data class by Kotlin annotations

```
DataClass("false","true")::class.members.filter {
     it.findAnnotation<Returnable>() != null
}
```